# how can we draw column chart with stacked column chart in a single high chart?

Tags: highcharts

How to draw a stacked chart and column chart in a single highchart
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you have to do is set the appropriate `x` value.

```
series: [{
  data: [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 5]
  ]
}, {
  data: [
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 4]
  ]
}, {
  data: [
    [3, 8]
  ]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4992/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data